# browser player overlaps hamburger menu

Tags: android, browser, z-index, uc-browser, xiaomi

Certain browsers like Xiaomi MI browser or UC browser on Android play website videos in their own video player. This is causing issues with hamburger menu of the site as it is going behind the player. I have tried to increase the z-index of the hamburger menu element but still it is not working. I also see the issue with major video content platforms like youtube (m.youtube.com) and hotstar (hotstar.com). Please find attached screenshots of the issue.

1. Is there any solution to solve this issue?
2. Can we access the player element from JavaScript for hiding?

[image: hotstar.com]

[image: m.youtube.com]

Comment: ideally what you should do it..whenever the menu is opening send the video view to back, and when it closes, bring it to front..

Comment: @Ashwani - Thanks for your reply! Could you post some code, it would be really helpful ?